# spring transaction xml schema

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, jersey

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <tx:annotation-driven/> 
.
.
.
</beans>
```

I have that on my `applicationContext` on a `Spring` application and I am getting this error on Eclipse:
*Referenced [file](http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx) contains errors . For more information, right click on the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details..."*

Comment: You have this twice `http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx`

Comment: Changed to this:

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

Still the same error

Comment: Which version of spring du you use?

Comment: I am using Spring 3.0.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line is missing in you applicatin context

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

Please try

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <tx:annotation-driven/> 
.
.
.
</beans>
```

Comment: Thank you Jens. It solved it. IDK how the hell I missed it :(